# Is there a API to know list of available sonarqube languages which requires update?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, upgrade

In Sonarqube administration page under update center I can see list of plugins which requires an update.

The same list of plugins will be shown in the response of /api/system/upgrades.

For sonarqube languages, I see a few items in Update Center saying that require an update. However the same list of languages not shown in /api/system/upgrades response.

Is this expected?

Is there a different API to get this details?